# How to delete an inherit property from yaml config?

Tags: dictionary, docker, yaml, docker-compose

I have a yaml file like this:

```
local: &local
  image: xxx
  # *tons of config*

ci:
  <<: *local
  image: # delete
  build: .
```

I want `ci` to inherit all values from `local`, except the `image`.

Is there a way to "delete" this value?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

No there isn't a way to mark a `key` for deletion in a YAML file. You can only [overwrite existing values](http://yaml.org/type/merge.html).

And the latter is what you do, you associate the empty scalar as value to the key `image` as if you would have written:

```
  image: null   # delete
```

There are two things you can do: post-process or make a base mapping in your YAML file.

If you want to post-process, you associate a special unique value to `image`, or a  specially tagged object, and after loading recursively walk over the tree to remove key-value pairs with this special value. Whether you can already do this *during parsing*, using hooks or overwriting some of its methods, depends on the parser.

Using a base mapping requires less work, but is more intrusive to the YAML file:

```
localbase: &lb
  # *tons of config*

local: &local
  image: xxx

ci:
  <<: *lb
  build: .
```

If you do the former you should note that if you use a parsers that preserve the "merge-hierarchy" on round-tripping (like my `ruamel.yaml` parser can do) it is not enough to delete the key-value pair, in that case the original from `local` would come back. Other parsers that simply resolve this at load time don't have this issue.

Answer (score 5):

For properties that accept a list of values, you can send `[]` as value.

For example in docker-compose you don't want to inherit `ports`:

```
service_1:  &service_1
    # some other properties.
    ports:
      - "49281:22"
      - "8876:8000"
    # some other properties

    image: some_image:latest

service_2:
    <<: *service_1
    ports: []  # it removes ports values.
    image: null  # it removes image value.
```

Comment: I noticed that this didn't work with docker-compose v1.29, but it did work with v2.5. The error I was getting with v1.29 was:

`services.node-exporter.networks contains an invalid type, it should be an array, or an object`